# fourier transform phase angle not matching

Tags: python, python-2.7, signal-processing

i am trying to get supplied value of phase angle in the fourier transform plot of frequency Vs phase angle. The frequency Vs phase angle becomes discontinuous at the desired frequency also the value of phase angle is correct in the plot.

```
from scipy import *

import sys

from math import atan2

x=arange(-10, 10,0.01)

T   = 0.1

f = 1/T

omega = 2*pi/T

amp = 0.3

y1=2*amp*sin(omega*x + float(sys.argv[1])*pi/180.)

y2=amp*sin(3*omega*x + pi/4)

y = y1+y2

from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, fftshift

fft_y = fft(y)

im = imag(fft_y)

r = real(fft_y)

angle=arctan2(im,r)

angle1 = fftshift(angle)

Amp= ((fftshift(abs(fft_y)))/len(y))*2

q     = fftshift(fftfreq(len(x), x[1]-x[0]))


from pylab import *

figure(1)

plot(x, y,'ro-')

figure(2)

plot(q, Amp, 'ro-')

figure(3)

plot(q, angle1*180/pi, 'g-')

show()
```

Comment: So your question is...?

Comment: how to get value of phase through FFT.

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: I am supplying value of phase angle through argument and i want to get, the same in the fft curve of frequency Vs phase.

Comment: You can threshold based on the magnitude to remove noise in the phase, e.g. `phase[abs(fft_y) < 1e-6] = 0.0`. That should leave just the components for 10 Hz and 30 Hz in the phase plot. The phase at 30 Hz should be -pi/4 (-45 deg). BTW, the `angle` function does the `arctan2` computation for you, with an option to return degrees, e.g. `phase = angle(fft_y, deg=True)`.